# error opening Emulator in flutter in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

error opening Emulator in flutter in android studio

NFO | Android emulator version 31.3.10.0 (build_id 8807927) (CL:N/A) emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\Andy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\ emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\Andy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\ W

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.